# How to commit a XA transaction after server crashed

Tags: mysql, transactions, linux-mint, xa, mysql-5.7

I'm using MySQL 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 on Mint 18. I found when I prepared a XA transaction, and then the server crashed. After the service restart, I can't touch the transaction anymore. It still locked the table.

> mysql> xa start '1';
>
> mysql> xa end '1';
>
> mysq> xa prepare '1';
>
> sudo killall -9 mysqld
>
> sudo service start mysqld
>
> mysql> xa commit '1';
>
> ERROR 1399 (XAE07): XAER_RMFAIL: The command cannot be executed when global transaction is in the  NON-EXISTING state
>
> mysql> xa start '1';
>
> ERROR 1440 (XAE08): XAER_DUPID: The XID already exists

The situation is similar with [bug71352](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71352), but my version is so far away.
Anything I missed?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem:

```sql
mysql> \! lsb_release --description
Description:    Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya

mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.19    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t` (
    ->   `id` INT
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> XA START '1';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `t`
    -> VALUES (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> XA END '1';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> XA PREPARE '1';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> XA RECOVER;
+----------+--------------+--------------+------+
| formatID | gtrid_length | bqual_length | data |
+----------+--------------+--------------+------+
|        1 |            1 |            0 | 1    |
+----------+--------------+--------------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

-- Killed mysqld from other session

mysql> \! service mysql status | grep 'Active'
   Active: inactive (dead) since 33s ago

-- Restared mysqld from other session

mysql> \! service mysql status | grep 'Active'
   Active: active (running) since 3s ago

mysql> XA RECOVER;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:
Current database:

+----------+--------------+--------------+------+
| formatID | gtrid_length | bqual_length | data |
+----------+--------------+--------------+------+
|        1 |            1 |            0 | 1    |
+----------+--------------+--------------+------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> SELECT `id` FROM `t`;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> XA START '1';
ERROR 1440 (XAE08): XAER_DUPID: The XID already exists

mysql> XA COMMIT '1';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `id` FROM `t`;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

The xa start must fail, this is expected, this is the pending XA transaction. You need to do an xa recover first.